# Laravel dynamic router

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.4

I am building a website for which the pages are all dynamic, the layout is the same, but with different content blocks. I am wanting to make it SEO friendly where each page url consists of any number of categories and then a page name. i.e. home.com/cat1/sub-ca2/sub-cat3/page-name.

The router has to get the slugs from the url and return a view with the appropriate product data to populate that view.

I have search in internet in vain to try to find instruction on how to make the router for this. Can anybody shed some light on how this can be achieved?

Thanks heaps in advance and thanks to the awesome Laravel crew, Laravel is the best!

Answer (score 1):

If **all** your URLs follow the same structure of ***home.com/cat1/sub-ca2/sub-cat3/page-name***, this is very simple in Laravel:

```
Route::get('{cat1}/{cat2}/{cat3}/{name}', function($cat1, $cat2, $cat3, $name) {
      return view($cat1 . '.' . $cat2 . '.' . $cat3 . '.' . $name);
});
```

If not all the pages follow the structure with 4 parameters in the URL, there is not a good solution to your problem. In order to route, you need some kind of predictability as far as URL structure goes so you know what parameter is in what place.

You can also offload this to a controller method as described in the Laravel routing documentation https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/routing#route-parameters

**Router**

```
Route::get(‘{cat1}/{cat2}/{cat3?}/{cat4?}’, ‘SomeController@index’);
```

**Controller**

```
public function index(Request $request, $cat1, $cat2, $cat3, $cat4) {
    // logic here
}
```

Comment: Thanks Rob, the number of categories will vary for each page, one could be site.com/digital-signage/outdoor/outdoor-digital-signage-page, there could also be site.com/digital-signage/digital-signage-page.

Is there anyway to have a dynamic number of slugs? The method in that documentation is for a finite number of slugs.

Comment: You can have some of them be optional, but you still have to know what position means what logically. You are definitely better off passing this to a controller and implementing whatever logic you need there

Comment: thanks rob, how can i pass the whole thing to a controller? I can work out the logic from there probably?
Can you forward '/*wildcard*/ to a controller?

Comment: I edited my answer to show the controller way of doing this. Sounds like at least 2 parameters are required so I made cat3 & cat4 optional in my answer